# On JavaScript regex alternation and character sets

Tags: javascript, regex

Maybe I'm stupid, but this problem really got me baffled.

```
var text = "aaa\naaa\naaa";
console.log("A: " + text.match(/(.|[\r\n])+/)[0]);
console.log("B: " + text.match(/[\r\n.]+/)[0]);
```

Output:

```
A: aaa
aaa
aaa
B:
```

I really don't see why. I think they should do the same thing (besides grouping stuff).

Another question which might be related:

I have a string read from a file created in a Windows system. I tried to match everything.

`/[\n\r.]+/` matches the entire string.

`/[\n\r.]+/g` does not (I got a lot of '\r\n' in the returned array).

but both `/[\s\S]+/` and `/[\s\S]+/g` matches the entire string.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(.|[\r\n])`  this pattern means any charcter | carriage return/new line
`[\r\n.]`    this one means carriage return/new line/literal dot

Comment: They seemingly do the same thing, the second one is an "\r", or "\n", or ".", whereas the first on it's either "." or any  "\r" or "\n" characters. Peculiar.

Comment: @rsn `.` means any character, `[.]` means literal dot.